# QTabWidget set mask on tabs (not tab content)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, mask, qtabwidget

I would like to round the corners of tabs (not the tab content) on the `QTabWidget` using the `setMask`. I have tried:

```py
tabs = QTabWidget()
tempTabWidget = QRoundedTabWidget()
tabs.addTab(tempTabWidget,"New Tab")
```

```py
#Tab widget that has rounded corners and
#inverted random corners at the bottom
class QRoundedTabWidget(QWidget):
  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(QWidget,self).__init__(parent)
    self.radius = 3
    self.tabHeight = 32
    self.setMask(self.roundEdges(self.rect()))

  def roundEdges(self,rectangle):
    self.tabWidth = InterClassVariables.resizeTabWidth

    region = QRegion()
    region += rectangle.adjusted(self.radius,0,-self.radius,0)
    region += rectangle.adjusted(0,self.radius,0,-self.radius)

    #Top left corner piece
    corner = QRect(rectangle.topLeft(),QSize(2 * self.radius,2 * self.radius))
    region += QRegion(corner,QRegion.Ellipse)

    #Top right corner piece
    corner.moveTopRight(rectangle.topRight())
    region += QRegion(corner,QRegion.Ellipse)

    return region
```

However, this puts a mask on the content of the tab, not the tab itself. Do I need to subclass the `QTabWidget` object to modify the `addTab` where the tab is actually built? Where do I call my sub-classed widget for the tab?

**EDIT**:

This is what I'm currently getting - the two top corners of the tab content are rounded:
[image: Content of tab has mask applied]

This is what I would like on the tab:

[image]

Comment: provide a [mre], also show an image of what you get and what you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual tab is a QTabBar. You can do this very easily with style sheets and the `border-radius` property to achieve the mask.

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), 'New Tab')
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(tabs)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QTabBar::tab {
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 6px;
            border-top-left-radius: 6px;
            border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        }''')
```

There is even an example in the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar).

About the inverted corners, I'm not sure if this is achievable with stylesheets but perhaps you could re-implement the paint event. `QPainterPath.quadTo()` will draw quadratic bezier curves.

```
class Tab(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel(text), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setBrush(QColor('#aaa'))

        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(0, h)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.1, h, w * 0.1, h * 0.75)
        path.lineTo(w * 0.1, h * 0.25)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.1, 0, w * 0.2, 0)
        path.lineTo(w * 0.8, 0)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.9, 0, w * 0.9, h * 0.25)
        path.lineTo(w * 0.9, h * 0.75)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.9, h, w, h)
        qp.drawPath(path)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Edit: Now to get a functional tab widget out of this unfortunately I think you have to reinvent the wheel a little bit. Here is a minimal example:

```
class Tab(QAbstractButton):

    def __init__(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel(text), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        color = '#ccc' if self.isChecked() else '#aaa'
        qp.setBrush(QColor(color))

        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(0, h)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.1, h, w * 0.1, h * 0.75)
        path.lineTo(w * 0.1, h * 0.25)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.1, 0, w * 0.2, 0)
        path.lineTo(w * 0.8, 0)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.9, 0, w * 0.9, h * 0.25)
        path.lineTo(w * 0.9, h * 0.75)
        path.quadTo(w * 0.9, h, w, h)
        qp.drawPath(path)


class TabWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.qbg = QButtonGroup(self)
        self.tabs = []
        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.setSpacing(0)
        vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        vbox.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QStackedWidget {
            background-color: #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }''')

    def addTab(self, widget, text):
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(widget)
        tab = Tab(text)
        tab.clicked.connect(self.setCurrentTab)
        self.tabs.append(tab)
        self.hbox.addWidget(tab)
        self.qbg.addButton(tab)

    def setCurrentTab(self):
        i = self.tabs.index(self.sender())
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(i)


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tabs = TabWidget()
        tabs.addTab(Widget(), 'Tab 1') 
        tabs.addTab(Widget(), 'Tab 2')
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(tabs)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. On a side note using stylesheets, do you know of a way to add inverse border radii onto the bottom corners of the tabs, to achieve a look similar to Google Chrome? Thanks again.

Comment: @SamG101 I'm not sure how to do it with stylesheets, but I edited the post with another way you could get that look.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks! Last thing, how would I actually add the `Tab(Qwidget)` into the TabBar, as opposed to it adding the normal `QWidget`? Thanks

Comment: @SamG101 I added an example of this, it sort of requires recreating the TabWidget, and subclassing the Tab from QAbstractButton instead. If it answers your question please approve.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect